# How can I limit ItemsSource binding execution in a TreeView to only visible TreeViewItems?

Tags: wpf

I have a TreeView that uses DataTemplates for the TreeViewItems, and each has an ItemsSource binding set up.  I have a huge number of items in this tree, so I'm wondering how I can limit ItemsSource executing only for tree view items currently on the screen.

Comment: Make sure your TreeView is virtualized.

Comment: My bad answer would be to calculate it. As I said, not a great answer, therefore, just a comment. But I definitely did that before.

Answer (score 0):

My best solution for this is within the opening `<TreeView>` tag, add `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" VirtualizingPanel.CacheLength="1"`.  I didn't bother to set the cache units because, from what I'm reading in the documentation, its default unit is in pages.  The end result of these settings is that the tree items on screen, one page worth above, and one page worth below are the only tree items that have their `ItemsSource` binding execute.